# Set array from Kotlin to Android spinner when spinner expects XML string array

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner, android-spinner

I have used Android's spinner for static values by setting `string-array` in XML resources. This works without issue.

However, for a specific spinner, I need to set data dynamically based on API returns. While I have set the returned values into an array of strings, when I send this to the adapter, it expects type `Int` (which a returned string-array from XML translates into).

I'm not sure how to make these arrays work within Kotlin to be received by the spinner.

```
val managerSpinner: Spinner = binding.spinnerManager
        val managerList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
        var managerArr: Array<String>

        viewModel.managers.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            if (null != it) {
                it.items?.forEach { manager ->
                    managerList.add(manager.fullname!!)
                }
                managerArr = managerList.toTypedArray()
                ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                        activity?.applicationContext!!,
                        managerArr!!,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
                ).also { adapter ->
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                    managerSpinner.adapter = adapter
                }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about like this:

1. it use `ArrayAdapter` constructor rather than using `createFromResource` function factory
2. use `addAll` [function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter#addAll(T...)) to add item

```
val managerSpinner: Spinner = binding.spinnerManager
        val managerList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
        var managerArr: Array<String>

        viewModel.managers.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            if (null != it) {
                it.items?.forEach { manager ->
                    managerList.add(manager.fullname!!)
                }
                managerArr = managerList.toTypedArray()
                ArrayAdapter(
                        activity?.applicationContext!!,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
                ).also { adapter ->
                    adapter.addAll(managerArr)
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                    managerSpinner.adapter = adapter
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Initially, this didn't work because it wouldn't consume the array.

So I attempted this while just using the MutableList, and that allows for it to set.

Thanks for guiding me to the right answer!

Comment: Also, I had to add a type of String to ArrayAdapter for it to work properly, but those are just minor fixes.